# I have a search icon that cannot be removed

Tags: screen, app-icons

I dont know why but since 2 days I am getting a search icon in my screen, I can move it and place it where ever I want but it will show in all my screens and also I cannot remove it.

thanks

[image]

Comment: Weird. Probably a stupid question, but did you try rebooting?

Comment: Is it an app shortcut? Can you long-press it and drag it to the "Remove" X?

Comment: dotVezz,I turned off and on again a few times an when restart is not there but after some min its appear. Dont want to erase everything what I have in my phone

Comment: Krampus, I can long press and move it but I have no the option to remove it :(

Comment: What device is this? Can you check your running apps and start to force close them and see if it disappears?

Comment: I have a nexus 4 with android 4.4.2
I tried going to settings->app and stop all the apps trying to make the icon disappear but it didnt :(
any other idea?

Comment: @iair007 Didn't see this as you didn't tag my name. I have the same device here and I've never seen that. I would imagine it is embedded in something you have installed. If you long press it and move it to 'app info' what does it tell you? Have you side loaded any dodgy apps on the device? Sonething LIKE this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saintalexispress.simplewidgets  but that is misbehaving on you would be the first guess. What happens when you click on the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks you all for your answers,
I have no idea what happen but yesterday I updated like 15 apps and now the icon is gone.
I dont know which app made that happens but the good news is that its gone :)

just FYI it didn't act like a regular app icon, it didn't gave the option to see "app info" or "remove" it was staying in all the screens no just in one. and when it was press it opened a search that when was press to search was searching on Google.

any way, thank you very much
greetings
Iair